# C++ return directly from operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

Is it allowed to directly return while we are sending to `ostream`?

For example, instead of writing:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Foo foo) {
    os << foo.a << foo.b;
    return os;
}
```

Instead, can I directly write:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Foo foo) {
    return os << foo.a << foo.b;
}
```

I tried it, and it seems to work but I don't know if it's the right thing to do. Is there any problem with doing the second version?

Comment: Did you try it with your compiler?

Comment: Yes it seems to work but I don't know if it's the right thing to do

Comment: It's safe and a pretty normal practice when implementing quite simple stream operators like your example.

Comment: It works because every of the overloaded stream operators returns `std::ostream&`. So, the whole expression after `return` returns `std::ostream&`. The stream operator (actually the `operator<<`) is left associative. Hence, `os << foo.a << foo.b` is evaluated as `((os << foo.a) << foo.b)`.

Comment: Why do you think it maybe wrong? If you don't add why think this would be wrong, we can't comment on it.

Comment: I added your comment to the question. It's generally preferable to do that, instead of writing it in a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two code snippets you post are *entirely* equivalent.

Why? Because (I'm assuming here, for the sake of argument, that `foo.a` and `foo.b` are simple data types like `int`) the [`<<` operator for `std::ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) returns a *reference to itself* (see the "Return Value" section in the linked document).

Thus, in your first code snippet, the `return os;` line returns a reference to the `os` object referenced by the first argument. In your second snippet, the two `<<` operations each evaluate as a reference to that same object ... so you are returning a reference to the *exact same* object.

To make the second version a bit clearer, you may like to enclose the returned expression in parentheses:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Foo foo) {
    return (os << foo.a << foo.b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it allowed to directly return while we are sending to ostream?

Yes, it is allowed.